# Coste computacional de mantener la instancia de una variable en Java

Tags: java, variables

Estoy realizando un estudio sobre consumo energético, y me pregunto si mantener la instancia de una variable conlleva un coste computacional (y energético por lo tanto) a lo largo del tiempo, más allá del consumo de memoria y del coste de crear la propia instancia.

Comment: Si no usas una variable no veo qué coste computacional puede llevar asociado... otra cosa sería que la instancia gestionase hilos o realizase esperas activas / pasivas o... pero tener tipos nativos en memoria únicamente conlleva una reducción de la memoria del sistema.

Answer (score 1):

Es extremadamente difícil estimar el coste computacional de una instancia de una clase en Java, pero tampoco se puede decir que vaya a ser cero aunque esa instancia no esté haciendo nada.

De entrada, la JVM tiene un mecanismo de recolección de basura cuyo funcionamiento depende de la implementación de la JVM que se esté usando e incluso la versión de Java. Lo cierto es que la recolección de basura sí tiene un coste computacional y este es mayor cuantas más instancias maneja un programa dado (incluso aunque esas instancias no hagan nada). Así que cada una de ellas contribuye algo, aunque sea poco, pero su contribución no es cero.

De ahí a estimar el coste computacional con el que contribuye cada instancia hay un camino muy largo, sería extremadamente complicado.

Comment: Efectivamente, el recolector de basura (garbage collector) es el encargado de limpiar las instancias de las clases que no se estén utilizando. En un principio, pensé en hacer variables nulas explícitamente en el caso en que no se volviesen a utilizar. Sin embargo, esta práctica no tiene ningún sentido actualmente (al menos en mi caso), ya que el recolector es cada vez más sofisticado y preciso. Al coste al que me refería no es al asociado al recolector, sino al hecho de que se encuentre dicha instancia en memoria, que podría hacer que hubiese un trabajo extra en el tratamiento de la misma.

Answer (score 0):

La instancia no va tener coste si no está realizando una tarea. Como la ejecución de alguno de sus métodos o un hilo. El único coste que tendría sería de memoria, pero es muy poco (depende de los datos que almacene), con una instancia no se nota.